# How to add/insert json data[0] etc to/in jquery $('td').css?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, json

Here is working code

```
$('td.transaction_partner_name_td4').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #FF0000');
```

It changes border color for such `html` `<td class='transaction_partner_name_td4'></td>`

But I need to use `html` like this

```
<td class='transaction_partner_name_td<?php echo $row_number;?>'>
<input type='text' name='transaction_partner_name[]' id='transaction_partner_name<?php echo $row_number;?>'>
</td>
```

`$row_number` may be 1, 2 ... 30. So `transaction_partner_name_td` may be `transaction_partner_name_td1,2...30`

Need in `ajax` after `function(data, success)` change `<td class='transaction_partner_name_td<?php echo $row_number;?>'>` for certain `td`

`json` `data` values are for example :

`data[0]` value is 1

`data[1]` value is 3

`data[2]` value is 4

I can change/set `input` value like this:

```
<?php while ( $counter < ($counter_maximum) ){ ?>
$('#transaction_partner_name<?php echo $counter;?>').val(data[<?php echo $counter;?>]);
<?php $counter++; } ?>
```

In the same way trying to change/set border color.

Tried

```
<?php while ( $counter < ($counter_maximum) ){ ?>
$('td.transaction_partner_name_td(data[<?php echo $counter;?>])').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #FF0000');
<?php $counter++; } ?>
```

But this does not work. With View source see like this `$('td.transaction_partner_name_td(data[1])').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #FF0000');`

Is it possible to add `json` `data[0]` to `td.transaction_partner_name_td`? Or may be other solution?

**Solution**

Thanks to T.J. Crowder advice at the moment get to work with this code (possibly latter will face some problems, but at the moment works as necessary):

```
<?php while ( $counter < ($counter_maximum) ){ ?>
$("#transaction_partner_name" + data[<?php echo $counter;?>]).closest("td.transaction_partner_name_td").css('border-bottom', '1px solid #FF0000');
<?php $counter++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's probably a better way to approach this structure entirely, but the *minimal* change to what you have that allows you to target those cells is this:

HTML *(Note that there's no longer a row ID on the class)*:

```
<td class='transaction_partner_name_td'>
   <input type='text' 
          name='transaction_partner_name[]' 
          id='transaction_partner_name<?php echo $row_number;?>'>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Access *all* of them
var allTransationPartnerCells = $("td.vtransaction_partner_name_td");

// Or access the one for a specific row
var justOneCell = $("#transaction_partner_name" + someRowNumber)
                                  .closest("td.transaction_partner_name_td");
```

Or in that last one, you probably don't even need the class:

```
// Access the one for a specific row
var justOneCell = $("#transaction_partner_name" + someRowNumber)
                                  .closest("td");
```

Comment: Need to access specific row, because for some rows need to change border color, for some, - not. As understand `$("#transaction_partner_name" + someRowNumber)` can use like `$("#transaction_partner_name" + data[0])`?

Comment: @user2465936: I dont' know what `data` is, but provided it contains a row ID, yes. The cell would be `$("#transaction_partner_name" + data[0]).closest("td.transaction_partner_name_td");` (or just `$("#transaction_partner_name" + data[0]).closest("td");`, probably).

Answer (score 1):

In case that `data` is an array of *row numbers*, you can filter the inputs and select their parent `td` elements:

```
$('input[name="transaction_partner_name[]"]').filter(function() {
    // Check existence of the numbers
    var n = + this.id.replace('transaction_partner_name', '');
    return $.inArray(n, data) > -1;
}).parent('td')
  .addClass('borderBottom');
```

You can also add `data-*` attributes to the `td` elements instead of creating dynamic classes, then you can select and filter them using jQuery `.data()` method:

```
<td class='transaction_partner_name_td' data-id="<?php echo $row_number;?>">
```

```
$('td.transaction_partner_name_td').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), an_id_array ) > -1;
}).addClass('borderBottom');
```